# Find an equivalent of an improper integral

Tags: real-analysis

It's an example given in my book after monotone convergence theorem and dominated convergence theorem (without explanation) :

Find an equivalent of $$\int_0^{\pi/2}\dfrac {dx} {\sqrt{\sin^2(x)+\epsilon \cos^2(x)}}$$

when $\epsilon\to 0^{+}$.

Inspired of the theorems, I naturally think of the sequence $(\epsilon_n)$ that converges to $0$, and it is monotone. However, the limit (1/sin(x)) doesn't converge in the integral (the other examples converge to a finite number...). Would someone give a hint about how to deal with the divergent case?

Comment: What do you mean with "Find an equivalent of"?

Comment: Denote the integral by $I$. We look for a closed form $f(\epsilon)$ s.t. $f(\epsilon)\sim I$...

Comment: I was typing my answer when came Robert Z's one ! He won the race about elliptic integrals !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*At least for the time being, this is probaly not an answer.*

Sooner or later, you will learn about [elliptic integrals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_integral) and, assuming $\epsilon >0$,
$$\int\dfrac {dx} {\sqrt{\sin^2(x)+\epsilon \cos^2(x)}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\epsilon }}F\left(x\left|\frac{\epsilon -1}{\epsilon }\right.\right)$$  where appears the elliptic integral of the first kind. This makes 
$$I=\int_0^{\pi/2}\dfrac {dx} {\sqrt{\sin^2(x)+\epsilon \cos^2(x)}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\epsilon }}K\left(\frac{\epsilon -1}{\epsilon }\right)$$ where appears   the complete elliptic integral of the first kind.

Now, you could use the expansion 
$$K\left(\frac{\epsilon -1}{\epsilon }\right)=\sqrt{\epsilon } \left(2 \log (2)-\frac{\log (\epsilon )}{2}\right)+\frac{1}{8}
   \epsilon ^{3/2} (4 \log (2)-\log (\epsilon )-2)+O\left(\epsilon ^{5/2}\right)$$ which makes $$I=\left(2 \log (2)-\frac{\log (\epsilon )}{2}\right)+\frac{1}{8} \epsilon  (4 \log (2)-\log
   (\epsilon )-2)+O\left(\epsilon ^2\right)$$ which clearly shows the limit and how it is approached.

Let $\epsilon=10^{-k}$ and compare the exact value with the above approximation
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 k & \text{exact} & \text{approximation} \\
 0 & 1.570796327 & 1.482867951 \\
 1 & 2.578092113 & 2.576026580 \\
 2 & 3.695637363 & 3.695601653 \\
 3 & 4.841132561 & 4.841132044 \\
 4 & 5.991589341 & 5.991589334 \\
 5 & 7.142772451 & 7.142772450 \\
 6 & 8.294051464 & 8.294051464
\end{array}
\right)$$

Comment: Is it $K\left(\sqrt{\frac{\epsilon -1}{\epsilon }}\right)$?

Comment: @RobertZ. This is the famous problem of notations in elliptic integrals !

Comment: Thanks a lot. I learnt something more than the question itself. (That's why I like this forum so much :)

Comment: @pqros. Same for me ! I learn every single day here. By the way, you are welcome.

Answer (score 2):

Let us consider the [complete elliptic integral of the first kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_integral#Complete_elliptic_integral_of_the_first_kind)
$$K(k) = \int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{d x}{\sqrt{1 - k^2 \sin^2 x}}.$$
Then
$$I_{\epsilon}:=\int_0^{\pi/2}\dfrac {dx} {\sqrt{\sin^2(x)+\epsilon \cos^2(x)}}
=\int_0^{\pi/2}\dfrac {dx} {\sqrt{1-(1-\epsilon)\cos^2(x)}}=
K\left(\sqrt{1-\epsilon}\right)$$
Now by [Asymptotic expansion of the complete elliptic integral of the first kind](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1111135/asymptotic-expansion-of-the-complete-elliptic-integral-of-the-first-kind), we have that the asymptotic expansion of $K(k)$ at $1^-$ is
$$K(k) = -\frac12 \ln(1-k^2) + O(1)\implies \lim_{\epsilon\to 0^{+}}\frac{I_{\epsilon}}{\ln(\epsilon)}=-\frac{1}{2}.$$

Comment: I am typing almost the same ! I shall continue with numerical aspects. Cheers.

Comment: This happens quite often. You are too fast for the old man. What do you think about the approximations I put in my answer ? By the way, where are you in Europe ?

Comment: Your approximations are fine (+1)! P.S. This user prefers to keep an air of mystery about him. ;-)

Comment: Is Europe $O(x)$ ?

Comment: No, it is $O(1)$... Apparently we are more than 1000km away.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will also read about the other 2 elliptic integrals :)