# Understanding asymptotic expansion of elliptic integral

Tags: asymptotics, elliptic-integrals

I am trying to understand the accepted answer by @Fabian to the post [Asymptotic expansion of the complete elliptic integral of the first kind](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1111135/asymptotic-expansion-of-the-complete-elliptic-integral-of-the-first-kind).

After a substituion the following integral is obtained

$$ K(k) = \int_{1-k^2}^1\!dy\,\frac{1}{2 \sqrt{y(1-y)(y-1 +k^2)}}$$

and the integral is  expanded  in $ \epsilon = 1-k$ to get

$$ K(k) = \int_{1-k^2}^1\!dy\frac{1}{2 y \sqrt{1-y}} + O(1)$$

@Fabian then adds that "<…>
The estimate of the error term follows from the fact that expanding in $\eta =1-k^2$, we have
$$K(k) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty c_n \eta^n  \int_{\eta}^1\!dy\, y^{-1-n} (1-y)^{-1/2}$$

with $c_n$ some constants <…>"

I cannot reproduce the calculation.
Going back to the first expansion of the integrand in $\epsilon = 1-k$  I calculated further terms

$$ \frac{1}{2 \sqrt{y(1-y)(y-1 +k^2)}} =  \frac{1}{2 y \sqrt{1-y}} +  \frac{\epsilon}{2 y^2 \sqrt{1-y}} + \frac{(3-y)\epsilon^2}{4y^3 \sqrt{1-y}} + O(\epsilon^3) $$

but I fail to understand how further process is achieved.
If I understood, the integral of the series is to be considered, and then the integral expanded in $\eta = 1-k^2$, but I do not understand how.

Let me rewrite the series expansion for the integral in terms of $k$

$$\frac{1}{2 \sqrt{y(1-y)(y-1 +k^2)}} =  \frac{1}{2 y \sqrt{1-y}} +  \frac{1-k}{2 y^2 \sqrt{1-y}} + \frac{(3-y)(1-k)^2}{4y^3 \sqrt{1-y}} + O((1-k)^3) $$

and the integral to be expanded in $1-k^2$ is
$$K(k) = \int_{1-k^2}^1\!dy \Bigg( \frac{1}{2 y \sqrt{1-y}} +  \frac{1-k}{2 y^2 \sqrt{1-y}} + \frac{(3-y)(1-k)^2}{4y^3 \sqrt{1-y}} + O((1-k)^3) \Bigg)$$

but I get quite stuck. Any suggestion would be most welcome.

Comment: I am wondering if there is anything wrong with the question, as I would have expected it to be an easy task for some of the fellow users on this site. Please do let me know if any improvement on the question side is needed.