# Series expansion of the Elliptic integral of second kind

Tags: elliptic-integrals

I want to calculate the series expansion of the function $E(1-x)$, where $E$ is the complete elliptic integral of second kind defined as

$$
E(x)=\int_0^{\pi/2} d\theta\, \sqrt{1-x^2\sin^2\theta}
$$

Mathematica result gives the following:
[[image: Series expansion of the function <span class=]$E(1-x)$." />](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C3Y9r.png)

From this, we can consider that $E(1-x)$ can be written in the form of

$$
E(1-x)=f(x)+g(x)\log x
$$
where $f$ and $g$ are Taylor expandable functions.

My questions are the followings:

1. Is my expecetation correct?
2. If so, how can I find the functions $f$ and $g$? Is it possible to find out the general form Taylor coefficients of $f$ and $g$? Or at least few terms? I found [Approximation for elliptic integral of second kind](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1093786/approximation-for-elliptic-integral-of-second-kind), which calculates the coefficients of the smallest order, but it seems that this method is a bit complicated to achieve a higher terms.
3. If not, what is the exact series expansion of the function $E(1-x)$?

I tried binomial expansion to $\sqrt{1-x^2 \sin^2\theta}$, which makes us possible to calculate the coefficients term-by-term, then tried to calculate the coefficients of $f$ and $g$, which does not work very well. The point which makes complication is that the function $\log x$ is not Taylor expandable, but $\log(1-x)$ is.

I also tried the following: assuming that $E(1-x)=f(x)+g(x)\log x$, we have $\log x = (E(1-x)-f(x))/g(x)$, and taking differential gives $1/x=[(E(1-x)-f(x))/g(x)]'$, removing the bothering $\log x$ function. However, this approach does not give any meaningful result also.

Comment: https://dlmf.nist.gov/15.9.E25 and https://dlmf.nist.gov/15.8.ii will probably help.

Comment: @Gary Combining 15.9.25 and 15.8.10 seems work. Thank you!

Comment: Could you write an answer to your question with details and results ? Thanks